# How to discover the type of media inserted in a DVD/CD drive? (java)

Tags: java, multimedia

When I insert a DVD or CD, I want to programmatically know what type of media(DVD or CD) is it.

Comment: Well it's going to be problematic, for sure, but I think you mean "programmatically".

Comment: I am sorry yes, I wrote it wrong. I found a software that does what I wanted to accomplish. Too bad at this time there seems to not be an universal solution (OS independent) for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO impossible to get this solved with pure Java. The only thing you can do is via the FileSystemView and detect whether a certain file is a cd/dvd drive but not if it contains a CD or DVD as media. Although a one can perform an educated guess by getting the total used space.

For a working solution you'll need at least JNI code for the three "big" OS. I'm not aware of any project that has done this. There are only platform specific libraries / utilities for Linux that use the usual cdrw/dvdrw tools in the background.

Comment: ...or at least suitable command line utilities to invoke and parse output from